# Prolog. Sum of the elements of two lists of different length

Tags: list, prolog, sum, element

Please help me!
I need to find sum of the elements of two lists of different length.
It should look like:

```
?-p([1,2,3],[1,2,3,9],L),write(L),nl.
L = [2,4,6,9].

p([],_,[]).
p(_,[],[]).
p([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H|T]):-H is H1 + H2,p(T1,T2,T).
?-p([1,2,3],[1,2,3],L),write(L),nl.
```

So I've got some troubles with different length of lists. I don't know how to do it.
Thanks for your help! Tanya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    p([], [], []).
    p([], [H2|T2], [L|Ls]) :-
      L = H2,
      p([], T2, Ls).
    p([H1|T1], [], [L|Ls]) :-
      L = H1,
      p(T1, [], Ls).
    p([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [L|Ls]) :-
      L is H1 + H2,
      p(T1, T2, Ls).
```

**Explanation:**
As long as there are elements in both lists, they get added and 'prepended' to L. Whenever there is 1 list empty, it will just 'prepend' them to L without adding it. When both are empty, the recursivity stops.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer shorter, deterministic code, where possible:

```
p([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs]) :-
    Z is X + Y,
    !, p(Xs, Ys, Zs).
p([], Ys, Ys) :- !.
p(Xs, [], Xs).
```